# Pandas use replace with a dict only if target column is empty

Tags: python, pandas

I create a df:

```
import pandas as pd
i = pd.DataFrame({1:['a','r','g','a'],2:[7,6,5,""]})
```

That is:

```
|  1  |  2  |
|-----|-----|
|  a  |  7  |
|  r  |  6  |
|  g  |  5  |
|  a  |     |
```

The last entry for a contains an empty string on column 2.

With the following mapping dictionary:

```
mapping_dict= {"a":'X'}
```

Current result:

```
i[2]=i[1].replace(mapping_dict)

|  1  |  2  |
|-----|-----|
|  a  |  X  |
|  r  |  6  |
|  g  |  5  |
|  a  |  X  |
```

Expected result, only empty column 2 are mapped:

```
|  1  |  2  |
|-----|-----|
|  a  |  7  |
|  r  |  6  |
|  g  |  5  |
|  a  |  X  |
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
i[2] = i[2].replace('',np.NaN).fillna(i[1].map(mapping_dict))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply replace your code of `i[2]` on the left of assignment statement to `i.loc[i[2] == "", 2]` to add a filtering condition.

Here, we use [`.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) to filter the row with the empty string on column `2` and specify column `2` as its second parameter to select the column to update.  Then, you can use your current `.replace()` code to achieve the desired result:

```
i.loc[i[2] == "", 2] = i[1].replace(mapping_dict)
```

**Result:**

```
print(i)

   1  2
0  a  7
1  r  6
2  g  5
3  a  X
```